Rolling motion and torque about a point on the ground
Why is the torque about any point on the ground on which a circular ring is rolling zero? The ground is rough. Please tell for both cases separately too where the ring has initial angular momentum zero, and initial linear velocity zero.

What all forces are acting on this ring? A force acting at the center of mass, parallel to the ground, can easily create a moment about a point on the ground. Do any of them change over the course of your observation?

Torque describes the offset distance of a force from the reference point. The contact force always goes through the contact point and thus the contact force always produces zero torque about the contact point.
There is a concept of the line of action of a force, as the locus of points where zero torque is produced. In this case, the line of action goes through the contact point.

For steady motion, the line of action goes through the center of the ring also providing zero torque on the ring.

For acceleration or decelerating motion, the line of action passes either ahead of the center of the ring, or behind, causing a net torque about the center of the ring.


